# How to print out arguments sent to a Mock::Object in perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking, arguments

I have a mock object

```
my $myMockObject = Test::MockObject->new();
```

If I call `$myMockObject->myFunction("my argument");`

... is there anyway of extracting `"my argument"` from the mock object in order to test whether the argument passed on to the mock object was correct?

Looks like methods `next_call(), call_args, call_args_string, call_args_pos` might help, but I can not get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide any implementation for `myFunction` (which is actually a method), so you can also store argument somewhere for testing. Something like:

```
use Test::More;
use Test::MockObject;

my $mock = Test::MockObject->new();

my $arg;
$mock->mock(myFunction => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    ($arg) = @_
});

$mock->myFunction("my argument");
is $arg, "my argument", 'correctly passed argument';

done_testing;
```